# how can I send a message with signalr to the client?

Tags: signalr

I want to use signalR for my clint browser website so it can receive messages from the server when a new order is added. So I want it to react to a server side event that is not triggered by any browser.

There are multiple users on the website. A user should be notified when there is a new order placed for him on he server. How an I notify only a specific user, and do this from the method that adds the user?

Is there any code like:

```
var chat=new Chat();
chat.Send("hihi");
```

placed in AddOrder method, with

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients     
        Clients.refresh(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default client id (used to identify the users browser window) and replace with your own.  Your client id would come from your membership provider.

Create a new class and implement IConnectionIdGenerator.

```
public class UserIdClientIdFactory : IConnectionIdGenerator
{
    public string GenerateConnectionId(IRequest request)
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

The method above just creates a new Guid, but you would return the customers id from your membership provider.

You then need to register this new class with SignalR dependencyresolver, so in the Application_Start method in the global.asax file add the following line

> GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IConnectionIdGenerator),
>   () => new UserIdClientIdFactory());

When a new order is placed you would then get the specific client and broadcast a message to them, for example:

```
    //clientId matches the user id from you membership provider.

    var clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext().Clients;
    clients[clientId].yourClientSideCallBackMethodGoesHere(someValue);
```

Comment: This solution has been deprecated. See the below question for more details on this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725051/signalr-iconnectionidgenerator-not-found-in-signalr-1-0rc2-release

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the `Context.ConnectionId` for all connected users, tie that to your website users and then use `Clients[connectionId].addMessage(data);`

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to hold a collection of Users (website users) each paired to a connection Id. You can then use SignalR events OnConnected / OnDisconnected to pop users in and out of this list.

E.g.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
     // Add users here with Context.ConnectionId
}

public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
     // Remove users from collection here by identifying them with Context.ConnectionId
}
```