# Signalr IConnectionIdGenerator not found in SignalR 1.0rc2 release

Tags: c#, signalr

I used to implement my own connection id generator with the following code:

```
public class MyConnectionFactory : IConnectionIdGenerator
{
    public string GenerateConnectionId(IRequest request)
    {
        return MyUserManager.Instance.CurrentUserID.ToString();
    }
}
```

This was working fine with SignalR 0.5.3 release but after updating to SignalR 1.0rc2 release the namespace or class name is not found. Also, I am not able to find any note on this breaking change here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md Can you help me fixing this issue?

Answer (score 5):

This is gone indeed and there is no direct replacement as you're supposed to do the user/connection mapping manually now.

I solved it using a HubPipelineModule and setting up a group for all connections of that user.

```
public class AuthenticationHubPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    protected override bool OnBeforeIncoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext context)
    {
        var id = MyUserManager.Instance.CurrentUserID.ToString();

        context.Hub.Groups.Add(context.Hub.Context.ConnectionId, id);

        return base.OnBeforeIncoming(context);
    }
}
```

When you then want to reach out to the user, you can just send it to that group like this:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHub>();
context.Clients.Group(userId).yourCallbackMethod();
```

Hope this helps,
Yves

Comment: I have the same issue, whilst I could use your code, could you explain what you mean by "you're supposed to do the user/connection mapping manually now"

Comment: For anyone reading this OnBeforeIncoming will not get called unless a call to the server is made. I believe GenerateConnectionId was called when hub.start was called